# How can I modify my Controller so that the query is limited to the user id?

Tags: php, laravel

I have my Controller set up as such:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Booking;

class eventController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $events = array();
        $bookings = Booking::all();
        foreach($bookings as $booking) {
                'id' => $booking->id,
                'title' => $booking->title,
                'resourceId' => $booking->resourceId,
                'start' => $booking->start_date,
                'end' => $booking->end_date,
            ];
        }
        return view('home', ['events' => $events]);
    }
}
```

Here I can pass everything from my DB into my view, but how can I filter these out such that only entries from a certain user_id is displayed? This is what my table looks like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rsj6S.jpg.

I have attempted to use the {user} blade but am stuck.

Comment: The code you posted in your question has syntax errors. and dont post images, or at least resume them in your question (like the database structure here)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this line:

```
$bookings = Booking::all();
```

to this:

```
$bookings = Booking::where('user_id', 9)->get();
```

Or if you want to get the logged in user, you can use `Auth`.

Add this line after `use App\Models\Booking;`

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
```

and then:

```
$bookings = Booking::where('user_id', Auth::id())->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

In your User model add the following function (a user may have many bookings)

```
public function bookings(){
    return $this->hasMany(Booking::class);
}
```

Get the logged in user by calling Auth::user();
like

```
$user = Auth::user();
$bookings = $user->bookings();
```